# Call to a member function update() on a non-object after using jQuery.get()

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to create a plugin to update variables in a Wordpress database table. I've got the following on my admin page

```
<button type="button" onclick='myfunction()'>Update</button>
 <script>
  function myfunction(){
    jQuery.get('<?php echo $plugin_url = plugins_url('plugin-name'); ?>/scan-update-table.php');
    return false;
  };
</script>
```

And the scan-update-table.php looks like this:

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->update('wp_scan_featured', array('post_ID'=>44), array('role'=>'lead_article'));

require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
dbDelta( $sql );
```

When I press the button nothing happens but when I open the the scan-update-table.php file I get the error: Fatal error: Call to a member function update() on a non-objec

Comment: 1.) make sure all your requires and includes are happening before you declare you globals 2.) your JS code is using single quotes, that string could give you issues. try changing `'plugin-name'` to `"plugin-name"`

Comment: Thanks @adeneo. How do I make it 'part of the Wordpress system'? How to I solve this problem?